# Why does it fail in downloading tweets on excel?

Tags: python, excel, search, cursor, tweepy

```
texto=[]
date=[]

api = tweepy.API(auth)

uno = tweepy.Cursor (api.search,q=`Bocconi`, rpp=100, result_type="recent",          include_entities=True, lang="it").items()


for i in uno:

    o = i.text
    g = str(o).replace('\n',' ').replace('\r\n', ' ').replace('%\n%', ' ').replace('\r', ' ').replace('%\r%', ' ').replace('%\r\n%', ' ') 

    texto.append(g)
    e=i.created_at
    date.append(e) 

Bocconi = pd.DataFrame(index=range(0,len(texto)))

Bocconi['texto']=texto
Bocconi['date']=date

Bocconi.to_csv("Bocconi.csv",sep='\t')
```

I get this specific failure:

> return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table) UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2714' in position 0: character maps to undefined> -

Comment: I get this specific failure:return codecs.charmap_encode(input,errors,encoding_table)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character u'\u2714' in position 0: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: thank you very much and sorry for the bad formatting which some of you so kindly corrected!